# Unable to move between Screens in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have two screens, one is empty and the other is Emacs' manual.
My cursor is at the empty screen.

All my commands affect the empty screen.

A similar command in Vim is C-w.

**How can you switch to the Emacs' manual** such that I can roll down the screen by C-v?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [zaczap said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742400/unable-to-move-between-screens-in-emacs/742406#742406) use "`C-x o`" (control "x" then "o") for moving between "frames" in a single window, or "`C-x 5 o`" to move between different windows.

---

By "window" I mean a window manager object with a title bar and decorations and all that, while "frame" means a part of a whole window set off to contain a single buffer.

---

Other important commnds:

- "`C-x 2`" to make a new frame in this window or "`C-x 5 2`" to make a new window
- "`C-x 0`" to close the current frame or "`C-x 5 0`" to close the current window
- "`C-x 1`" to make the current frame expand to use the entire window.

Answer (score 4):

**Control-x + o** (C-x + o), google emacs cheat sheet for help

1. hold Control
2. press X
3. release Control and X
4. press O

Answer (score 2):

You can also scroll the other screen (“window” in Emacs terms) without leaving the screen you're currently in:

Meta (Alt) + PageUp/PageDown

Answer (score 0):

Emacs cheat sheet - heavy rotation commands
^ : CTRL key
M : Esc or ALT key

Emacs   ^h i    manual

^x^c    quit            ^d  delete next char
^x^s    save            BACKSPACE   delete prev char
^x^w    save as
^x u    undo            M-d delete next word
^g      abort command        M-BACKSPACE    delete prev word

^f  --> char           ^k   delete to end of line
^b  <-- char
^p  /\ up               ^-SPACE     start region
^n  / down             ^w  cut
                        M-w copy
                          ^y    paste
M-f next word ->
M-b prev. word <-
                        ^x b    switch/new buffer
                            ^x^f    open file
^a  beginning line
^e  end line               ^s   search
                        M-g g   go to line

^v  screen / down
M-v screen /\ up        ^x 0    delete window
                        ^x 1    delete other windows
                        ^x 2    split vertical
                        ^x 3    split horizontal
                        ^x o    delete current window